# Check to see how many times a number appears consecutively from user-specified input file

Tags: java

The goal of this program is to check how many times an integer appears consecutively in a given file. The program prompts the user for the file and then reads the file. This file is called "integers.txt" and the program is supposed to keep track of which number appears for the longest consecutive run. I'm having issues with the program not considering two numbers consecutive due to the way java tokenizes things. The program doesn't consider two numbers consecutive if there is a tab between them in the given file, although it is supposed to. To add to that, if there are multiple runs of consecutive numbers with the same length of consecutive numbers that appear, it will print out all of the multiple runs. It is supposed to print only the first occurrence, but must also run through the rest of the program to make sure that there aren't any other runs that have a longer length. If it didn't have to check for any longer runs, then I'd be able to stop the code after getting what I needed.

Not allowed to use arrays in my code.

**Issues**

Consecutive numbers are only being considered consecutive if they are not separated by a tab/line (fixed)

Can't keep track of the longest consecutive run that appears first. Gets replaced by whatever run comes next. (fixed)

**Question**
Why isn't the program seeing consecutive numbers that are separated by a line and/or tab(s) as consecutive? How do I fix this?

Also, if there are two runs of the same length (i.e. how there are four 5's and four 3's), how do I only print out the first run and still make sure it is the longest? The issue I would have right now is that it would print out saying there are four 5's and also four 3's.

**INPUT FILE (Integers.txt)**

```
12 2 3 3 98 23   4  4  4 5 
5 5 
      5  21 21 21 -3 -3
-1 2 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3
```

**Program that checks runs**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LongRun {

public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = getInput(console);
    int prevInteger = input.nextInt();

    int count = 1;
    int maxCount = count;
    int consecutiveInteger = 0;
    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        int nextInteger = input.nextInt();
        if (prevInteger == nextInteger) {
            count++;
            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                consecutiveInteger = prevInteger;
            }
            prevInteger = nextInteger;
        } else {
            count = 1;

            prevInteger = nextInteger;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The longest run: " + maxCount + " consecutive " + consecutiveInteger
            + "'s");
}

public static Scanner getInput(Scanner console)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the file of integers: ");
    File inputFile = new File(console.nextLine());
    while (!inputFile.canRead()) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist. Try again.");
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the file of integers: ");
        inputFile = new File(console.nextLine());
    }
    return new Scanner(inputFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, you are skipping integers, because you are calling `nextInteger = input.nextInt()` at the end of your two `if` conditions, then discarding that and grabbing a new integer when the loop restarts. Get rid of those last `nextInt()` calls. Also, what is `scanForLongestRun()` for? I don't see you keeping track of the longest run anywhere.

Comment: `scanForLongestRun()` is a method that is basically going to be the while loop that is in the main method. I can't figure out a way to keep track of what run would come first and be the maximum length, so I stopped working on it because until I get the rest of the code right.

Comment: So just to clarify, do you want to print out the longest run for *each* given integer that appears in the file? Or do you want to find the single number that has the longest run and just print that out?

Comment: Could you give a better explaination of your problem?

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Comment: find the single number that has the longest run and print that out. all of the print statements are there just so I can see what my program is doing and try and fix it to the best of my knowledge

Comment: my question now is how do I get the program to keep track of what run is the longest and what the consecutive number is that corresponds to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add another variable to store both the integer and the longest number of count and update these information only if current count is bigger than longest count stored?

Comment: Does this use just an if/else statement, or does it use a for loop with a nested if/else?

Comment: You just need to use if/else statement. Do the check on whether the current count is bigger than the largest count stored after you increase the count for current number.

Comment: Worked accordingly after listening to your advice. Thanks.

Comment: glad to be of some help.

Comment: The only way I've seen so far to find a maximum value for something was through a for loop, and for some reason I didn't think I could still accomplish that in a while loop. XD